# Change windows form app (exe) icon at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, exe

I found a lot of questions around this subject, but none answered mine.
I have a chat application, and it's required that I change the app icon in the task bar when a message is received and not yet seen, and change it back again when all messages are seen.

I was able to do this successfully when running the app from VS2013, using this code in the displayed form:

```
if (count == 0)
{
    this.Icon = Properties.Resources.Icon1;
}
else
{
    this.Icon = Properties.Resources.IconNotification;
}
```

however when I publish my app and run the exe, the icon is not being changed.

Note that app icon is mainly set from VS, Application bar in project's properties (Icon and manifest), but I added Icon1.ico and IconNotification.ico to application's resources (Build Action set to Embedded Resource).

What am I missing to make the icon in the task bar change from exe too?

Comment: Why don't you start the published version and attach VS debugger to it to know what's happening?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I did that, and it's running and executing those code lines normally :S

Comment: Can you confirm that (in the debugger) the icons are the correct ones?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath SOrry but I want to be sure of what do you mean with "in the debugger".. because when I run from the debugger the icon is being changed successfully.

Comment: I mean: publish the application, attach the debugger to it, and right before the icon change, mouse-over the Icon1 and IconNotification properties to see if the files are what you want

Comment: @cFrozenDeath it does not show anything on mouse-over!

Answer (score -1):

Add Application.DoEvents() after updating the icon,

```
if (count == 0)
{
    this.Icon = Properties.Resources.Icon1;
    Application.DoEvents();
}
else
{
    this.Icon = Properties.Resources.IconNotification;
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```